# Why did Brainwave have to fight Skyfox if what he told Raikou was true?

Tags: jupiters-legacy

While inside the mind of the Blackstar clone,

> Brainwave encounters Skyfox and proceeds to have genuine battle (there is no one there to observe them and Lady Liberty arrives only later).

But later Brainwave admits to Raikou that

> he cloned Blackstar.

If so, why would he encounter such a potentially lethal threat inside a construct that should not have contained any?

Answer (score 1):

I would use the phrase "apparently lethal" rather than potentially. Everything in the whole episode needs to be seen through the lens of Brainwave's manipulation of events.

While Brainwave may not have expected to be observed, he does have to keep in mind that the Union members are Heroes. They can be expected to put their lives at risk to save others and his privacy inside the mind of the Blackstar clone cannot be guaranteed.

Additionally it's not clear how much Raikou was expected to be able to observe of the situation inside the Blackstar clone's mind. In the final reveal scene we see that a significant amount of information about Brainwave's plan has been leaked to Raikou, the dialogue suggests this is by simple proximity.

It can be safely assumed that struggle with Skyfox inside the clone's mind is another layer of distraction built into Brainwave's strategy. What better way to keep the monitoring people certain that a struggle is taking place than to engage in a struggle, even if it means running both sides of the table.